# Haftara reading customs

Tags: minhag, synagogue, tzibur-community, navi-prophets, haftarah

There seems to be a wide range of customs with regard to reading the *haftara*. In some shuls (mostly Chassidic) the one who is called up recites the berachah, and everyone then says the *haftara* quietly to himself.  In other places the *oleh* (or the *baal keriah*) reads the passage out loud from a single-volume Tanach. And there are yet others who read it out loud from an actual Navi scroll.

Why is there such disparity between these practices? Is there some kind of dispute as to what the *haftara* reading requires?

Comment: +1. And in some the _ole_ or _baal k'ria_ reads it aloud while everyone reads silently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Taame Haminhagim*, *kuntres acharon* to 341,](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=171) cites [*sidur Arizal*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20484&pgnum=163) as saying that each person must read the *haftara* and cannot fulfill his obligation by hearing it from the *ole*. In a footnote, *TH* points us to *P'ri M'gadim* [*EA*] 284:5, which says that, since *haftara* requires a *minyan*, one must listen to the reader, but that someone reading quietly can listen to the reader; this relates to our question, as it allows one to read along (though it does not mandate it). *TH* then points us to *Eshel Avraham* 282:9; however, I checked both *EA*s (*PMG* and Buczacz) and found nothing relevant at that paragraph.

I can also relate what my father taught me when I was growing up, which is (when not the *ole*) to read along quietly with the reader if he's reading other than from a *k'laf* (scroll), and simply to listen if he has a *k'laf*. I don't, however, know a source for this.

Comment: See [Maaseh Rav 136](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33900&st=&pgnum=34).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few pages on the Haftorah practice found in the Breuer Tikkun.

It suggests that the traditional custom was to have one Haftorah reader, just like the Torah reading. That everyone would chime in out loud may have begun to spare from embarrassment someone who was called up to read and wasn't doing very well with it.